# cast an integer converted to varchar and appended with a string to a datetime

Tags: sql, datetime, integer, sql-server-2012, varchar

I can't figure out why this sql code snippet does not work:

```
cast(cast(b.remodelyear as varchar(5)) + '-01-01' as datetime)
```

Remodel year is an integer consisting of a year (ex: 2012).  I cast it to varchar and append a month and a day to it and then I cast the whole thing to a datetime.

This one works:

`cast(cast(Yr as varchar(5)) + '-' + cast(Mth as varchar(5)) + '-' + '01' as datetime)`

Where did I go wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Please specify the RDBMS that you are targeting by adding the appropriate tag (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc.). There may be answers that take advantage of language or product features that are not universally supported. Also, by tagging it with a specific RDBMS, your question may receive attention from people better suited to answer it

Comment: Good point!  Sorry I forgot to mention it is SQL Server 2012.  Can I edit my post title to specify that?

Comment: Are you sure that is the code that is causing the error?  It is working on the following demo --- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d36a7/1.  What is the exact error message that you are getting?

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: Why varchar(5) for a 4 digit number (ie year)?

Comment: The error I received is the following:  `Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.` The varchar 5 vs 4 is just inattention. I changged it.

Comment: Actually I see that the problem is due to my data.  I have nulls and other values that may be causing the problem because when I use my initial code applied to just one row that I know has values it works.  Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I wouldn't concatenate strings for this, I'd perform some (trivial) date math:

```
SELECT DATEADD(year, b.remodelyear - 1, '00010101')
FROM <sometable> b
```

(note that I'm assuming SQL Server - [read this blog post](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries) for the reasoning behind the date format.  If you're using a different RDBMS this'll need to be translated).
I'm curious as to why you're casting to `varchar(5)`, as pretty much every RDBMS I'm aware of would throw an error if it encountered a fifth digit.

Comment: I'm actually not doing date math.  Rather I'm trying to create a date in the format '2012-01-01' from just a year integer (2012).

Comment: The issue is resolved. I see that the problem is due to my data.  I have nulls and other values that may be causing the problem because when I use my initial code applied to just one row that I know has values it works.  Thank you for the help!